# How can I get the Abusive Jerk achievement?

Tags: achievements, analogue-a-hate-story

I'm being too nice to *Hyun-ae, dammit! I can't figure out how to be an abusive jerk to her. What's the trick here?

Comment: I *think* I got the achievement by "pulling out early" and running `download` before the game told me to - but I can't be 100% sure and there seems to be no conclusive information about this on the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are apparently multiple ways to get this achievement as discussed [here on the Steam forums](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2800330);

Apparently the quickest way is to start the game, speak to  *Hyun-ae and tell her:

- you don't care what she has to say,
- that you like the society described because women aren't worth a thing,
- tell her her opinions are stupid and that the Pale Bride was overly dramatic

> She will eventually tell you that you're an idiot and that you're no different from the people on the ship back then (thus 'Treat her with the sort of respect she's used to') and then she will terminate your connection, basically ending the game.
>
> You can achieve this about 5-10 minutes after starting the game, even before gaining su access and activating mute.

Comment: Although that apparently hasn't worked for everyone. I was just reading that thread, and some people have gotten it by leaving her on the ship, or having reactor issues. Apparently that achievement is a bit bugged.

Comment: @SaintWacko Leaving her on the ship gives you "Forever Alone." Attempting to download data during the reactor countdown gives you "Failure to Prioritize."

Comment: The Reactor post is actually for the "Failure to Prioritize" achievement

Comment: Yes, but some of the posts in there say that they got this achievement from those activities.

Answer (score 1):

I got this achievement on accident, attempting to figure out what "Failure to Prioritize" would be. I disabled the communications array, terminating my connection. My guess is that because that's what Hyun-ae does when you piss her off, that set the flag for the achievement. So if you can't bring yourself to be mean, apparently you can be stupid.